# Override !important in gravity forms using js/jQuery/css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm trying to override a styling in gravity webforms in wordpress which is using !important

The code I'm trying to override is `<label class="gfield_label" for="input_1_20">Street Name<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label>`

CSS for that section is;

```
.gfield_label {
  margin: 10px 0 20px 0 !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  clear: both;
}
```

I would be happy to override everything with the class="gfield_label"

I have tried the following with no success;

one

```
jQuery('gfield_label').attr('style', 'margin: 15px 0 5px 0 !important;');
```

two

```
( '.gfield_label' ).each(function () {
    this.style.setProperty( 'margin', '15px', '0', '5px', '0', '!important' );
});
```

three

```
jQuery( ".gfield_label" ).css( "cssText", "margin: 15px 0 5px 0 !important;" );
```

four

```
label[for=input_1_20] .gfield_label {
    margin: 15px 0 5px 0 !important;
    }
```

I've tested jQuery on the site and it is working.

The custom CSS and jQ is loading at the bottom of the page, way after the links for the css files gravity forms uses.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry! what's the question? Did you try using CSS to override with a parent  class, such as `.parent-class .gfield_label { margin: 15px 0 5px 0 !important; }`

Comment: Finally smashed it with this `#form-bg .gfield_label {
  margin-top: 15px !important;
  margin-bottom: 5px !important;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Go to the settings of the plugin and switch "output css" to "No".

These guys must learn how to style. All their !importants made me a headache

Answer (score 0):

You can easily override these using css by puttiing following code after `<?php wp_footer(); ?>`     in your footer.php

```
<style>
label[for=input_1_20] .gfield_label {
    margin: 15px 0 5px 0 !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Won't this get overwritten every time I update the theme? Also my theme won't let me edit this.